# turning off log for script generated files on nginx stops file generation

Tags: wordpress, nginx, debian

I'm trying to turn off log for robots.txt file on nginx which is generated by Wordpress like:

```
location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
```

And i'm getting 404 error when try to get http://domain.com/robots.txt, could you explain, why? What is the correct syntax?

nginx version: nginx/1.2.1
WP version: 3.5.1

Comment: Does the file load without that line present?

Comment: does the file actually exist on the filesystem or is it generated by WordPress?

Comment: @doublesharp it is generated by WP.